# MIDI-Keyboards with integrated audio?

Tags: keyboard, midi, midi-controller-keyboard

I'm looking for a MIDI keyboard with integrated audio interface so I can play without plugging in to the computer. There were few products like *M-Audio ProKeys* and *M-Audio Keystation 49i* but these products are discontinued.

Is there any reason why they were discontinued? Are there any other products available now?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want a keyboard that can act both as a MIDI input device and also synth on itself?  If so, you can use any digital piano, e. g. Yamaha P-105

Comment: @MischaArefiev The ProKeys does not have an audio interface, so what is meant is a synthesizer.

Comment: @CL. ProKeys Sono 61 and 88 does have built in audio (about 10 instruments), and I'm basically looking for a MIDI keyboard not a synthesizer.

Comment: @flopr: The Sono 61 and 88 actually have built in 128 General MIDI range of instruments plus 46 drum sounds. The 5 or 10 high quality instruments have dedicated buttons but you can access the others. The Sonos incorporate MIDI-keyboard, sound synthesis and a basic audio mixer (e.g. for guitar and mic). You only need external monitors. As in CLs answer, stage-piano is a useful term for this class of devices.

Comment: There's an enormous range of integrated keyboard synthesizers; what's your budget? What range of sounds do you need? Do you need sequencing capability on the keyboard itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except at the "toy" end of the market, almost any synthesiser or electric piano you can buy today will have MIDI in and out.

Reading between the lines, I suppose the challenge you have is that you want a good keyboard, with budget sounds. That may be difficult to find.

I would recommend shopping around and basing your shortlist on the mechanical aspects of the instrument -- if you want it to feel like a piano, look at digital pianos; if you want it to feel like an organ, look at more "synthy" keyboards.

Then ensure that MIDI in and out is supported. Just for futureproofing, you should check:

- that you can use the keyboard to control other sound modules.
- that you can control the sound module from another MIDI source (like a sequencer)

It's an unusual keyboard that doesn't meet these requirements -- but you should check just in case.

... and finally, when you are trying out the instruments in the shop, use the sounds it makes as a deciding criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Only M-Audio knows why they were discontinued.
(I'd guess that they were not able to keep updating their drivers, which were needed because they were using a non-standard protocol.)

There are many MIDI keyboards with integrated synthesizer; they are called [stage pianos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stage_piano).

Comment: From what I recall, the special drivers were for low-latency. In situations where latency was not an issue, you can use standard USB-MIDI drivers.

Comment: In my world, there are many MIDI keyboards with integrated synthesizer; they're called synthesizers or keyboard synthesizers.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The protocol itself has exactly the same latency as that defined in the USB audio specification. Early Windows drivers were inefficient; the M-Audio protocol is deliberately incompatible to prevent the Windows driver from being used, and it's not possible to use the standard driver with those M-Audio devices. Later M-Audio devices are using the standard protocol. (Roland built some devices where you could choose between standard and custom drivers.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason he may need this is that with built-in audio interface you can hook up your laptop with your controller keyboard via USB and play vst-s or au-s live without having to use the tiny mini plug output on your laptop to get your sound into the stage box. A guess, but this is what I would do.